# Parsing of a phrase

Tags: nouns

According to Cambridge dictionary meaning of

**make a name** is **to become famous or respected by a lot of people**

How to parse this phrase

To become famous or to become respected??

Comment: to make a name for oneself, himself, herself. It is already parsed, so I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is an example of omission of parallel parts of two phrases.

> To become famous
>
> or
>
> To become respected by lots of people.

It is possible to form passive-like phrases.  "He became respected by lots of people" means "Lots of people came to respect him".

Comment: Is it correct to say, He became disliked by others?